# How to make python program use different installation

Tags: python, linux, bash, scrapy

```
>> which python
/usr/bin/python
>> python --version
Python 2.4.x
```

My problem is very simple, how do I run a python program on a different installation of python (e.g. /usr/bin/python26)?

I want to be able to run Scrapy with a different python installation than the default, but the question is meant for any program written in Python running on a Unix-like system.

EDIT: To clarify, I want to run an installed program which someone else wrote and is usually run like so:

```
scrapy crawl blaha
```

NOT like so:

```
python scrapy crawl blaha
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, under Unix systems, you have multiple Python executables, for example, on my system:

```
which python
/usr/bin/python
which python2
/usr/bin/python2
```

The name of the executable gives the version of the application. This is [the standard for different versions of Python, as defined in PEP 394](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/). To hint at which version your script should use, the normal thing to do is provide a hashbang. For example, on my system, Python 3.x is the default Python, so if I write a 2.x script, I add:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

Then, when my script is run (`./some_script.py`) it will use Python 2.7.3.

You should avoid using just `#!/usr/bin/env python` as it will do different things on different systems. If they are following the specifications, `#!/usr/bin/env python2` should point to 2.x and `#!/usr/bin/env python3` should point to 3.x - under Arch this works correctly (with just `python` pointing to 3.x (unusually) as well).

## Update for your edit:

If you want to do that, the easiest route is to make an executable in your system path that simply runs the command `python some_script ...`.

This is done regularly, for example, `eclipse` on my system actually runs `/usr/bin/eclipse` - a bash script that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
export ECLIPSE_HOME=/usr/share/eclipse
export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true
${ECLIPSE_HOME}/eclipse "$@"
```

So for your problem, just make a script somewhere in your path (let's say `/usr/bin/scrapy`) which contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
python2 scrapy "$@"
```

I would note that in future, you should try to give as much information about your problem as possible up front, not changing it after getting answers.

Comment: Point well made @Lattyware. I didn't think that people would assume that one would only run their own program instead of existing packaged programs such as in this case

Answer (score 1):

How are you running your program? Does it have the execution bit set and you have the first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Then, well, just do:

```
#!/usr/bin/python26
```

Or, you can just do:

```
>> python26 your-awesome-python-script.py
```

Regarding your edit: Since you can't / don't want to change the third party program (scrapy) you need to either:

- relink `/usr/bin/python` (do an `ls -l` on it. You will see that it points to the `python24` executable, do an `ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/pythonXY` or similar to relink this)
- create an alias for `scrapy` in your `.profile`
- create your own scrapy shell script that does the proper incantations (e.g. running the script with your preferred interpreter)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look to [VirtualEnv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) which is designed to let you use different versions of python on your installation.

If you want to use an already installed python version, just use `python2.6` instead of `python` if you want to use python2.6.